# Separate taskset arguments from the command arguments

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I want to run a command which looks something like this :

```
taskset -c 10 ycsb -p "redis_host=1234"
```

The actual command is :

```
ycsb -p "redis_host=1234"
```

But argument `-p "redis_host=1234"` is taken by taskset as it argument and throws an error :       `Failed to set pid 0's affinity:`

-p "redis_host=1234" is an argument to ycsb command. shell miss understands that and takes it as an argument for taskset.

Comment: The `-p` option takes a `PID` as its value with an optional `[mask]`. Generally a `PID` is a single numerical number not, for instance, `"redis_host=1234"` as you have in both your examples above. What are you trying to accomplish by giving that argument? You can find the `PID` of any process by using the `pidof` command (e.g. `pidof bash`)

Comment: `-p "redis_host=1234" ` is an argument to ycsb command. shell miss understands that and takes it as an argument for taskset.

Comment: A linux parsing bug, or is it a taskset parsing bug? Does `taskset 0x0000000A ycsb -p "redis_host=1234"` work any better?

Comment: @JeffY No it's no good. I am looking or a escape character kind of thing.which would tell that -p is not for taskset but for the command.